# How add custom field in cart and sent in the order

Tags: magento, checkout, cart

I have one question about shopping.  I need aggregate one field Giftwrapped your order? Yes No.  name=giftwrap id=giftwrap value=functionevalue(Radio) this validation is javascript and function, no problem with this.  Now i have take the value giftwrap and send to group ajax and show this value in checkout review before confirm order, and then send the comment: the gift should be wrapped in the orden in the backend.  I try, i search but no nothing functioned, please help.

Comment: How can anybody possibly solve your problem when you don't provide any code?

Comment: when, i ask. how make that create one variable in magento cart.phtml and read in the checkout onepage?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Order Attributes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Amasty/extension/3920/order_attributes) extensions. It does exactly what you want for a relative cheap cost.